# Google result shows my websites javascript folder

Tags: javascript, google-search

I don't know why this is, but when I check my website on Google via site:lipedesign.dk (Which is my website), the last 4-5 results are something in my JavaScript folder. I am not quite sure why this is happening? Do you?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a robots txt in your first directory? Example below.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /js/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your server set up to display directory indices. Since a directory index is an HTML page, it is served like any other, and Google will index it like any other. If you don't want it to be indexed by Google, either add a `Disallow` in your `robots.txt` or just disable directory indices on that folder.